# mypy doesn't understand copy.copy

Tags: python, mypy

I'm having issues getting mypy to understand that the functions `copy.deepcopy` (and also `copy.copy`) from the `copy` standard library are callables. Even more so when these functions are assigned to a variable via a `x if y else z` expression. Below I included an example with two generic functions, to illustrate that the issue is not the assignment itself. The code itself runs without any errors and the lists at the bottom all print to the expected results.

However, when running mypy over this code, I get three different error messages, included below.

The generic example works fine, both with `map` and using list comprehension, no errors:

```
def add(x: int) -> int:
    return x + 5

def mult(x: int) -> int:
    return x * 5

do_mult = True
myfct = mult if do_mult else add

numbers = [2, 3, 4]
list(map(myfct, numbers))  # ok
[myfct(i) for i in numbers]  # ok
```

First set things up, no issues so far:

```
import copy

do_deepcopy = True
copyfct = copy.deepcopy if do_deepcopy else copy.copy

numbers = [2, 3, 4]
```

Here's where it get's weird:

```
list(map(copyfct, numbers))  # error
```

produces:

```
error: No overload variant of "map" matches argument types "function", "List[int]"  [call-overload]
```

and some notes about possible overload variants.

If I try the same thing using a list comprehension instead of `map`:

```
[copyfct(i) for i in numbers]  # error
```

I get:

```
error: Cannot call function of unknown type  [operator]
```

Now if I apply the function directly, without the assignment to a variable, the list comprehension case is accepted by mypy:

```
[copy.deepcopy(i) for i in numbers]  # ok
```

However, trying the same with `map`

```
list(map(copy.deepcopy, numbers))  # error
```

will get me:

```
error: Argument 1 to "map" has incompatible type "Callable[[_T, Optional[Dict[int, Any]], Any], _T]"; expected "Callable[[int], _T]"  [arg-type]
```

I do not know what's going on here, it seems to me as though mypy has some issue understanding the `copy` functions.

Regarding versions, I'm running mypy 1.1.1 and python 3.9.16

Comment: Looks like a [bug](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6697) with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and Generics.

Comment: I don't think `map` has much to do with the first issue. `reveal_type(copy.deepcopy)` and `reveal_type(copy.copy)` both produce nicely generic types. `reveal_type(copyfct)`, on the other hand, seems to throw up its hands and produce `builtins.function`. `map` just doesn't seem to get much to work with.

Comment: `mypy` can't seem to infer the type of `copyfct` with a `bool` variable. Changing it to `do_deepcopy: Literal[True] = True` helps provide the correct type to `copyfct`, at which point you are left with just the `map` issue.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/10740). I hope a Mypy expert will see this.

Comment: I posted [an example of a remedy for this](https://gist.github.com/relent95/310d612fa2a46bd86709d1e4334a69ae).